# Python code does not make changes to my track database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to make changes to a database that stores information of tracks in a system from reading metadata of each track from an xml file. However, when I execute my code, my changes do appear on the database.

Python code that creates tables and inserts information to tables in my track database

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER, 
);
''')

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = 'Library.xml'

def lookup(d,key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found: return child.text 
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key:
            found = True 
    return None

fh = open(fname)
data = fh.read()
stuff = ET.fromstring(data)

all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict Count:', len(all))

for entry in all:
    if (lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None):
        continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None:
        continue

    # print(name, artist, album, count, rating, length, genre)

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id) 
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, len, rating, count, genre_id) 
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''', 
        ( name, album_id, length, rating, count, genre))

    conn.commit()
```

Library.xml (There's more tracks but this the format of my data source)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-11-24T11:12:10Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.3.1.23</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>B7006C9E9799282E</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>369</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>John Deacon</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Greatest Hits</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Rock</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>4344295</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>217103</integer>
            <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>3</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>17</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>1980</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2006-02-14T16:13:02Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2006-02-14T16:12:53Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>160</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>55</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3518868190</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-04T19:23:10Z</date>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-10-14T23:31:47Z</date>
            <key>Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
            <key>Normalization</key><integer>1511</integer>
            <key>Compilation</key><true/>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>21130E105F3B8845</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>File Type</key><integer>1297106739</integer>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Compilations/Greatest%20Hits/03%20Another%20One%20Bites%20The%20Dust.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
..... more data 
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is quit correct but maybe there is some typo, may be that's why it's not working so refer to this code here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('assignment_trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')


fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    #added this
    genre = lookup(entry,'Genre')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None:
        continue

    print(name, artist, album, genre, count, rating, length)

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
    #Added this
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
        ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )

    conn.commit()
#Added this
sqlstr = 'SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID and Track.album_id = Album.id AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id ORDER BY Artist.name LIMIT 3'

print
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
    print(str(row[0]),str(row[1]),str(row[2]),str(row[3]))

cur.close()
```

it will surely help you.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiTableDB.py", line 72, in <module>
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable